# How do I create a class to capture user input with differing argument types?

Tags: java, class, oop

How do I create a class to capture commands with differing argument types?
To capture commands with similar argument types to operate a door object by swinging, e.g. `(Swing, DoorNo, swingAngle)`, I'd create a class as follows;

```
class DoorCommand {
     private String commandName;
     private int doorNo;
     private float swingAngle;

     public DoorCommand (String cmdName, int doorNo, float swing angle) {
        // set values here
     }

     // do all the setter and getter here
}
```

My question is, I need to enable and disable doors' lock by using `(Lock, ENABLE/DISABLE)` as argument. How do I accommodate this in my `DoorCommand` class?  I want to be able to store DoorCommands in a list; `List<DoorCommand> doorCommands = new ArrayList<DoorCommand>();`

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for comment. I see your point, but at the moment, I can't get around my head about implementing Visitor Pattern. I'll look into it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), it allows you to create each command as a subclass of a common interface and therefore store the commands in a list for historical or undo purposes. In your case:

```
// The basic interface for all door commands
public interface DoorCommand {
    public void execute(Door door) throws CommandException;
}

// The Door class is the recipient for all commands
public class Door {
    private List<Command> history = new ArrayList<Command>();
    private int angle;
    private boolean locked;

    public void addCommandToHistory(Command command) {
        history.add(command);
    }

    // Getters and setters.
}

// The command to open the door
public class OpenDoor implements DoorCommand {
    public void execute(Door door) throws CommandException {
        door.addCommandToHistory(this);
        if (door.isLocked()) {
            throw new CommandException("Door is locked, cannot open");
        }
        if (door.getAngle() < 90) {
            door.setAngle(90);
        }
    }
}

// Another command, LockDoor
public class LockDoor implements DoorCommand {
    public void execute(Door door) throws CommandException {
        door.addCommandToHistory(this);
        door.setLocked(true);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the commands like this:

```
public void operateDoor() {
    Door door = new Door();
    new LockDoor().execute(door);
    new OpenDoor().execute(door);
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass the `Door` object to commands using a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you extract interface for door command, say `IDoorCommand`?

Then make `DoorCommand` from your example implement it (I'd change the name to more relevant actually, something like `SwingDoorCommand`).

Then add another command, implementing `IDoorCommand`, say `DoorLockControlCommand` that closes/opens lock, depending on constructor argument.

This way you'll be able to store both types of commands in `List<IDoorCommand>` and invoke them without need to know details if what command does.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question right. It seems to me that your commands are just storing the information of the operation, they are not operating on the door, e.g. changing the door's instance variables etc., right? If you're willing to change this, you could use the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Perhaps that's already your plan. The command then had to consider the `Door`'s state when executing.

Comment: Yes, just store information about the commands. Executing it is not a problem at the moment. But creating the class of the command is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a visitor pattern.

Your command has a method that accepts a `Door` and acts upon it.

You loop over your `DoorCommand` objects and send each one the `Door`, it does what it want to do.

This way your `DoorCommand` logic is separated from the `Door` and also you don't need one massive `DoorCommand` class to implement all possible commands.

Here is a simple example:

```
static class Door {

    private final String name;

    public Door(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void accept(final DoorVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

static interface DoorVisitor {

    void visit(Door door);
}

static class SwingCommand implements DoorVisitor {

    private final float swingAngle;

    public SwingCommand(float swingAngle) {
        this.swingAngle = swingAngle;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Door door) {
        System.out.printf("Swing door %s by %s%n", door, swingAngle);
    }
}

static class LockCommand implements DoorVisitor {

    private boolean locked;

    public LockCommand(boolean locked) {
        this.locked = locked;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Door door) {
        System.out.printf("Door %s is locked: %s%n", door, locked);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Door door = new Door("Front Door");
    final List<DoorVisitor> commands = new LinkedList<>();
    commands.add(new SwingCommand(0));
    commands.add(new LockCommand(true));
    for (final DoorVisitor c : commands) {
        door.accept(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this using **polymorphism**.

```
public class DoorCommand {
    private String cmdName;
    private static List<DoorCommand> list;

    static interface DoorCommandBase {
        void doAction(Object... arg);
    }

    class SwingCommand implements DoorCommandBase {
        void doAction(Object... arg) {
            int doorNo;
            float swingAngle;

            cmdName = arg[0];
            doorNo = arg[1];
            swingAngle = arg[2];
            // action to be performed
            updateList(arg);
        }
    }

    class LockCommand implements DoorCommandBase {
        void doAction(Object... arg) {
            boolean istrue;

            cmdName = arg[0];
            istrue = arg[1];
            // action to be performed
            updateList(arg);
        }
    }

    public static void updateList(Object... arg) {
        // update list
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```